# How to open firefox through ssh from ubuntu to windows?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssh, firefox, browser

I'm trying to open firefox while being connected through ssh on an ubuntu computer towards a windows 10 computer.
I connected with the command **ssh -Y -X user@localip4address**
I am connected to it, as I can clearly go through all files.

Using the command **start firefox https://google.com** opens firefox on the windows 10 computer when executed on the computer itself, but it does not do this through the ssh connection.

Any ideas on how to open a firefox window through the ssh connection?

Comment: To be clear, you're sitting in front of the ubuntu system, connected remotely to the windows system, and you want to run Firefox on the windows system? Which system should firefox display its windows on?

Comment: I'd like to open my Windows system's firefox on my Ubuntu system.